# Map (purrr) to add a range of numbers to a column one by one

Tags: r, predict, purrr

I have a `R` dataframe with two columns, colA and colB, and a fitted glm object.
Now, I can use predict with the dataframe and the glm object to predict the outcomes. However, I would also like to predict the outcomes for colB+0.1, colB+0.2, colB+0.3, etc.

I was thinking about doing this with `map` (purrr package), but I'm not sure how. What I've tried so far is to create a vector:

```
library(tibble)
range <- data_frame(colC = seq(-1, 1, by=0.1))
```

Now I can't figure out how to do:

1. Add the first element of colC to all elements of colB
2. Then predict() on colA and colB with the glm object
3. Group this result by colA and save it to a new vector
4. Repeat 1-3 for the next elements in colC and append the results to the new vector, so that this new vector has colC and the predicted and grouped colB.

I hope that my question is clear. Anyone knows how to do this?
By the way, it doesn't need to be with `purrr`.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a simple solution using a function so that you can do this for any data frames (`data`) and any sequence of added values (`add`) to "colB".

```
# data has a column named 'colB' from which we cant to predict with added values.
# add is the vector of adding values to colB
'glm_add' <- function(data, add = seq(0.1, by = 0.1, length.out = nrow(data))){
  data <- cbind.data.frame(data, colB_add = data$colB + add)

  glm <- glm(colA ~ colB, data = data)
  glm_add <- glm(colA ~ colB_add, data = data)

  pred <- predict(glm, data)
  pred_add <- predict(glm_add, data)

  return(list(pred = pred, pred_add = pred_add))
}
```

Reproduce an example to test the function :

```
data <- data.frame(colA = rnorm(10), colB = rnorm(10))
res <- glm_add(data)
```

Predictions from the glm with the initial "colB" as covariate:

```
> res$pred : 
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10 
0.13415502 0.17283282 0.27074470 0.47279826 0.01846426 0.13072748 0.21737383 0.12426569 0.25197290 0.30230644
```

Predictions from the glm with colB+0.1, colB+0.2, colB+0.3, ...  as covariate :

```
> res$pred_add
          1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10 
 0.19407251  0.23911968  0.39659313  0.75172751 -0.13896182  0.04575049  0.18184197 -0.02324061  0.19078440  0.25795416
```

---

## EDIT :

The author actually asked **to predict from any modified data frames where `colB_add` has each of its elements were added the same value 0.1, then 0.2, etc.**

To do this, I'll use `lapply()` to create a `data_list` where each element is a dataframe with appropriate `colB_add` column.

```
add <- seq(0.1, by = 0.1, length.out = nrow(data))
data_list <- lapply(1:length(add), function(i) cbind.data.frame(data, colB_add = data$colB + add[i]))
```

Then, I put each predictions into a list

```
pred_list <- list()
> lapply(1:length(add), function(x){
+   glm <- glm(colA ~ colB_add, data = data_list[[x]])
+   pred_list[[x]] <<- predict(glm, data_list[[x]])
+   })
[[1]]
          1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10 
-0.25321920  0.93795112 -0.04791986 -0.51229077 -0.20971718  0.36441752  0.38477508 -0.26853199 -0.00754999  0.04868279 

[[2]]
          1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10 
-0.25321920  0.93795112 -0.04791986 -0.51229077 -0.20971718  0.36441752  0.38477508 -0.26853199 -0.00754999  0.04868279 

[[3]]
          1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10 
-0.25321920  0.93795112 -0.04791986 -0.51229077 -0.20971718  0.36441752  0.38477508 -0.26853199 -0.00754999  0.04868279
```

Note that this gives the same predictions for each modified data frames. This is obvious from theory on linear models since every covariates changes by the same factor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this adds the first element of 'add' to the first element of 'colB', the second to the second, etc. I would like to add the first element of 'add' to ALL the elements of colB, then calculate predict and save the result, then add the second element of 'add' to ALL elements of colB and recalculate predict and save the result, etc.